# jquery single var for two ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two variables for two different classes. I want to assign single variable two both classes.e.g, the classes "signup" and "join" should be accessed using single variable like singup.

```
<head>
<script>

    var signup = $("signup");
    var join = $("join");
    signup.on("click",function(){

        alert("Signup");

    })
    join.on("click",function(){

        alert("Signup");

    })

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="signup">Signup</div>
    <div class="join">Join Now</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Its not working.
In header there is a class named signup
and in main there is another class with same name
and in script
var singup = $(".signup");
its working for header class but not for main class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access it since you use `$('join')` instead of `$('.join')`. Anyway, you can make it like this.

1) Ugly Approach

```
var elements = [];

elements.push( $('.join')[0] );
elements.push( $('.signup')[0] );

iterate using .each function
$(elements).each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        alert('Signup');
    });
});
```

2) Make a reference for the function

```
var signupClick = function() {
     alert('Signup');
});
$('.join').on('click', signupClick);
$('.signup').on('click', signupClick);
```

3) Comma separated

```
$('.join, .signup').on('click', function() {
        alert('Signup');
});
```

4) Add some class(prefered)

```
<div class="signup button">Signup</div>
<div class="join button">Join Now</div>
```

Then you can do some like this.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() { alert('Signup'); });
```

Comment: <header>
<div class="home">Home</div>
            <div class="signup">Join Now</div>
            <div class="login">Login</div>
</header>
<div id="home">
<div class="signup">
                Join Now
            </div>
</div>
In script tag
var signup = $(".home");

Comment: you have an id of `home` and a class of 'home'?

Comment: sorry in script i have used $(".signup");

Answer (score 2):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
var signup = $(".signup, .join");
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to select your elements is with the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). i.e.:

`$(".signup")`

as Arun noted, you could use the multiple selector, but there is really not much of a point in assigning those elements to variables.

Your code could be re-written like so:

```
$(".signup, .join").click(function() {
    alert("Signup"); 
});
```

Keep practicing -! Play around in your browser's javascript console - 
And heed the error log - !